# Analyze Python source code using Python and Inspector

Tags: python, static-analysis

I'm developing a static analyzer tool in Python that analyzes Python code for a given .py file and extract the body of classes, methods, etc in order to analyze code metrics (methods size, inheritance, and so on).

I identified the library "Inspect" that seems to suit me. However, I noticed that all the examples provided in the official documentation and external website only use this library by passing concrete instances of objects or functions that they want to analyze; however, I would like to analyze the source code without creating concrete instances of them, to avoid possible compiler errors due to missing library or other factors.

There is possible alternative methods or libraries that I can try to do it?

Comment: For rolling your own static analyzer perhaps the `ast` module would help. If you don't want to reinvent the wheel, perhaps an existing static analysis tool can be used. `Pylint` looks promising in that it ships with a tool called `pyreverse` which generates UML diagrams for a program. This would capture the inheritance relations that you mention.

Comment: Writing your own static analyzer is a *massive* task. Working with an existing static analyzer to get the metrics you want would be a lot more realistic and less error-prone.